# "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS" when I send Redirect "/"?

Tags: java, spring, eclipse

I am using Spring for java framework.

HomeController.java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)

return "home"**
```

index.jsp

```
response.sendRedirect("/");
```

I intended that [index.jsp]->[Homecotroller]->[home.jsp].
But there is an error

> "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS"

Why is there an error??

Plus. There is a 'welcome-file-list' for index.jsp in Tomcat servers web.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Index.jsp will fire on "/" if your server is setup with default document "Index.jsp"

This means infinite loop redirect, which the browser then terminates with ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

You would need to make a decision, change Home to listen on "/home" and have Index.jsp redirect to "/home", or have HomeController just take the job of Index.jsp

Comment: Thank you so much, and sorry for late accepting. Have a good day :)